# libav: where to get a reference to AV_PIX_FMT_NV12 when using cuda/cuvid?

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

Say I'm using `av_hwdevice_find_type_by_name("cuda")`, as in [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/hw_decode.c#L165). I need to convert the decoded frames to RGB using a `SwsContext`. I know, by experience, that when using the cuda/cuvid decoder I get frames in the `AV_PIX_FMT_NV12` format, even though every struct I look at says either `AV_PIX_FMT_NONE` or `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P`.

On what field of what struct can I get the `AV_PIX_FMT_NV12` value so I can remove my hardcoded source format on my call to `SwsContext.sws_scale`? Thanks!

**Update:**

Looks like I can get it by:

```
AVCodecContext* avctx;
...
frames_ctx = (AVHWFramesContext*)avctx->hw_frames_ctx->data;
AVPixelFormat pixel_fmt = frames_ctx->sw_format;
```

...once at least one frame has been decoded. Not sure if it's the correct way though.

Answer (score 0):

As for CUDA, your best bet will be when see `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P` on `AVHWFramesContext::sw_format` consider it as `AV_PIX_FMT_NV12` and when `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P10` it is actually `AV_PIX_FMT_P010`.

As far as I know, neither CUDA nor NVDEC(was CUVID) support anything other than 420 format as decoded frames.

Comment: That's basically what I'm already doing and what I want to avoid (eg, assuming something based on prior knowledge). But see my update above, I can actually get the AV_PIX_FMT_NV12 at runtime now. Just wondering if it's the correct/universal way.

Comment: Perhaps after decoding, what you did is correct way. I was assuming before decoding.